# Phonegap camera.getPicture() missing file extension and header data

Tags: image, cordova

I've been struggling on this for a while.

When I upload an image in a phonegap application with camera.getPicture() and ft.upload() the image is uploaded without file extension. I read it was because of a cache thing, providing a link to the actual file entry or something.

It was annoying me but I moved on since the image was uploaded fine on my server and displayed fine too even without file extension.

But today, we figured images were sometime rotated by 90°.

I instantly made the connection between the missing part of the image data and this issue, and I guess (not sure) I am right on this point.

I read image rotated by 90° could be caused by missing header meta data, so I guess not only the file extension were missing after all..

Could someone explain me what am I missing in the code and what to do or in which direction to look ? That would be awesome.

Here is part of my code (I can give you more if needed)

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(function(uri) {
  try {
    var imageURI = uri;
     ...
     var ft = new FileTransfer();
     ft.upload(imageURI, "some_script.php", function(r) {
       ...
```

Note:The image stored in database seems fine, the issue happens when the image is displayed in an  tag.

Here an example of file getting rotate once uploaded (I added manually the .jpg extension so I could upload it on noelshack otherwise not able to). As you can see, the link to image is OK but once in  tag it gets rotated

- http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2015/41/1444168922-35-1444166605.jpg
- http://jsfiddle.net/c3ybkqt8/

**tl;dr**

**How to upload an image file entirely with phonegap including file extension & metadata header and not only a sort of cached file entry.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> iOS Code

```
 function capturePhoto() {
     navigator.camera.getPicture(uploadPhoto, onFail, {
                     quality: 50, 
                    // allowEdit: true,
                    correctOrientation: true,
                    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URL,
                    // destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL
                    sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA
                  }
                                             );
    }

    // function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {
    // localStorage.setItem("ImageData",imageData);
    // localStorage.setItem("captureImgFlag",captureImgFlag);
    // window.location = 'profileUserImgUploadInGallary.html';
    // }

    function onFail(message) {
    // alert('Failed because: ' + message);
    }

    function uploadPhoto(imageURI){
        console.log(imageURI);
    spinnerplugin.show();
    var UserId = localStorage.getItem('UserId');
    // imgPostGallary
    // var img = document.getElementById('imgPostGallary');
                // var imageURI = img.src;
                // var imageURI = imageData;
                // img.src = imageURI;
    // var ImageDataUp = localStorage.getItem('ImageDataUp');
    // var imageURI = ImageDataUp;
    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.fileKey="file";
    options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    options.mimeType="image/jpeg";

    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    ft.upload(imageURI, encodeURI("http://XYZ/uploadimg?user_id="+UserId+""),  winGallary, fail, options);
    console.log(ft.upload);
    }

    function winGallary(rGallary) {
        console.log("Code = " + rGallary.responseCode);
        console.log("Response = " + rGallary.response);
        console.log("Sent = " + rGallary.bytesSent);
        spinnerplugin.hide();
        window.location = 'profileUserImgUploadInGallary.html';
    }

    function fail(error) {
    console.log("upload error source " + error.source);
    console.log("upload error target " + error.target);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, this code is working fine on both android and ios. maybe windows too I'll try but I guess it will

Comment: ya this code working in almost all platform and without  any error. & Thank You BelgianR.

Answer (score 0):

**Hello, here is full example it's working for me capturing photos and set in image tag and upload that photos on server. and still you have facing any problem message me.**

```
<img id="profileImageId">
    <script type="text/javascript">
                var profileImage = '';
                function profileCapturePhotoEdit() {
                  navigator.camera.getPicture(profileonPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, {
                    quality: 50, 
                    // allowEdit: true,
                    correctOrientation: true,  // using this your image not roted 90 degree
                    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
                    sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA }
                                             );
                }

                function profileonPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {
                  localStorage.setItem("imageDataProfile","data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData);
                  var imageDataProfile = localStorage.getItem("imageDataProfile");
                  document.getElementById('profileImageId').src = imageDataProfile;
                }

                function onFail(message) {
                  // alert('Failed because: ' + message);
                }

              </script>

              <!-- uploadProfileImage -->
            <button onclick="uploadProfileImage();">
              Upload Profile Image
            </button>

               <script type="text/javascript">
              function uploadProfileImage() {
                var UserId = localStorage.getItem('UserId');
                var img = document.getElementById('profileImageId');
                var imageURI = img.src;
                var options = new FileUploadOptions();
                options.fileKey="file"; // your file key in your .php file change here
                options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
                options.mimeType="image/jpeg";  // your extension

                var ft = new FileTransfer();
                ft.upload(imageURI, encodeURI("http://XYZ?user_id="+UserId+""), winProfile, failProfile, options);
              }

              function winProfile(r) {
                console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode);
                console.log("Response = " + r.response);
                console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
                // alert('Send success');
              }

              function failProfile(error) {
                console.log("upload error source " + error.source);
                console.log("upload error target " + error.target);
              }

            </script>
```

Comment: Thanks to your code, I figured how to get the correct metadata. All my code needed was to change Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI to Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL and add "data:image/jpeg;base64," to imageUri variable in success callback.
But it still give me a file without extension, but whatever since image is correctly displayed now

Comment: However, according to the phonegap doc : The image quality of pictures taken using the camera on newer devices is quite good, and images from the Photo Album will not be downscaled to a lower quality, even if a quality parameter is specified. Encoding such images using Base64 has caused memory issues on many newer devices. **Therefore, using FILE_URI as the 'Camera.destinationType' is highly recommended.**

Comment: It doesn't work on IOS. I keep getting error code 1 file not found even tho the image is displayed in the <img> element